# Git copying branches from one organization's repo to other organization's repo

Tags: git, github

As of now, we are working in one organization who is having admin permissions for a repository. That repository has many branches among which three is ours.

We need to copy that three branches along with master from their organization's repository to our organization's repository (which is empty as of now).

All the webhooks installed in that, should be copied as well. Condition being: No files should be lost from either of the repositories. We just need a copy of it to do things from our own.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, clone the repository locally.

```
~$ git clone git@github.com:org1/repo.git
~$ cd repo
```

Then, add another remote to that repository.

```
~/repo$ git remote add origin2 git@github.com:org2/repo.git
```

Now you have two remotes: origin points to org1/repo.git, and origin2 points to org2/repo.git.

So now, you want to push all of the branches of your local repo to your second remote:

```
~/repo$ git push origin2 --all
```

That should get you most of the way there. But it will not copy the webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

> We need to copy that three branches along with master from their organization's repository to our organization's repository (which is empty as of now).

#### What can you do?

- Clone the original repo
- Add new remote `git remote add <origin2> <url2>`
- Use the code from both the repositories inside a single repo

Now you can pull and merge the branches from the 2 remotes and have the code of both of them in a single repository.

As you can see in the image below you will have 2 repositories  which builds up your big repository.

```
# clone first repository
git clone <repo1>

# add remote 
git remote add <remote2> <url2>

# display the list of all the remotes
git remote -v

# now add your branches to what ever branch you want
# you said that you need 3 branches so simply check them out from originX
# and push them to origin Y
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The -all did not work in my case. I used:

```
git clone <upstream-repo-url/repo.git> --mirror
cd <repo>
git remote add <your-remote-name> <your-remote-url/repo.git>
git push <your-remote-name> --mirror
```

[git push all branches from one remote to another remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884832/git-push-all-branches-from-one-remote-to-another-remote)