# git push all branches from one remote to another remote

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have two remote: upstream and origin. upstream is something I can't push to. origin is my own repo. How can I fetch all branches from upstream and then push them to origin?
I tried:

```
git fetch upstream
git push --all origin
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Verify remote url's with 'git remote show'

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37797245/3723423) help ?

Answer (score 109):

I just needed to copy one repository from Bitbucket to GitHub, these are the steps assuming your remote is called origin, all branches and tags will be copied:

```
git remote add neworigin url-to-new-remote
git push neworigin --tags "refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*"
```

Good thing about this is that files in your working copy won't be modified.

Comment: Is `--force` required? Maybe add `--tags` to include these?

Comment: @DavidTchepak Oh yes, you're right. --force isn't needed, In my case was because I had conflicting code in the target repo. And yes, --tags will copy the tags. I have updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I like this answer for repos that are already checked out.  The only downside I see is that it pushes "HEAD" as a branch to the remote in addition to the local branches and remote branches.

Comment: Finally, a working answer which doesn't require all the remote branches to be created locally, nor a special 'bare' clone, nor a 'mirror' clone

Comment: If you want to do it from the website instead of the commandline, github's got an 'import repository' functionality (click on the '+' top right & see dropdown menu), where you can import repos from other websites.

Comment: Was getting error `zsh: no matches found: refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*` until I wrapped the refspec in quotes e.g. `""refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*"`

Comment: can I confirm that this is copying from origin to neworiginand not the other way round?

Comment: In my opinion this is more deserving of up upvotes than any other answer - I am intrigued as to why it hasn't more upvotes

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, does precisely what the OP asked for

Comment: I got many `remote: GitLab: You cannot create a branch with an invalid name.` errors from this.

Comment: To address the comment by @Nejuf you can remove the symbolic HEAD ref and re-add it after the sync. `git symbolic-ref --delete refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` should remove it and `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master` should recreate it (assuming master was the branch it pointed to).

Comment: @MaxCarroll: Yes, it copies from `origin` to `neworigin` (this is what happened when I ran the command).

Answer (score 88):

You may want to try cloning your upstream repo with `--mirror` option and then push to your new remote with `--mirror` option too

You'll have the following flow:

```
git clone <upstream-repo-url/repo.git> --mirror
cd <repo>
git remote add <your-remote-name> <your-remote-url/repo.git>
git push <your-remote-name> --mirror
```

⚠ Be really careful with the `push --mirror` as it will **delete** branches that are on your `<your-remote-name>`

Comment: How would you do if you don't want to create a clone, just to work from your current repo?

Comment: the second line gave me the error `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)`

Comment: looks like I needed to `cd` into the cloned repository firt

Comment: @DavidAmmouial, if you already cloned the upstream repo just do both of the last steps.  But I guess if you want to work from your local repo it's just the standard git workflow, doing them locally and pushing them remote, nothing to do with the initial question or do I miss something?

Comment: You're right @NickoGlayre, the original question does mention a local clone.

Answer (score 14):

One complete answer of cloning from one (bare) repository to another (bare) repository taking ALL branches, not just the checked out ones, is to clone a local bare repository as an intermediary. Then all branches are pulled as part of the clone and a git push --all will push them all. Example performed on Windows from github to gitlab:

1. git clone --bare git@github.com:robe070/cookbooks.git
2. cd cookbooks.git
3. git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:robe071/cookbookstest2.git
4. git push --force --all gitlab
5. git push --force --tags gitlab

Result: 25 branches pushed to gitlab

Note, git checkout is not required for all the branches and meaningless to a bare repo anyway.

Comment: Our need was to take an internally hosted git repo and move it to GitLab. Because our repo was not visible outside the firewall we could not use GitLab's importing or pull mirroring options (on Gitlab.com). 

We also had an option to use the GitLab Community Edition for which we could use importing, but with a 3 hour limit that our largest repos would exceed. And pull mirroring is not available in GitLab CE.

So the option above will always work because it only relies on git functionality.

Comment: I'd recommend *not* using `--force`, unless you absolutely know you need it. Otherwise this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

When you `git push <REMOTE> --all` or `git push <REMOTE> --tags` all branches and tags will push from your local history into the REMOTE. In this way, if you want `push` all of the branches and tags from a remote (i.e. *origin*) (not only your local history) to another remote (i.e. *upstream*) **do the following procedure:**

1. Recieve all branches and tags from the origin and remove unmatched branches in your local history with the origin remote:

   - ```
     git fetch --prune
     ```
   - ```
     git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
     ```
   - ```
     git fetch --all
     ```
2. Add new remote url:

   - ```
     git remote add upstream <the-url-path-of-a-remote.git>
     ```
3. Now, your local is synchronized. Next, you can `push` all of the branches and tags to the new remote:

   - ```
     git push --all upstream
     git push --tags upstream
     ```

---

### TL;DR

```
git fetch --prune
git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
git fetch --all
git remote add upstream <the-url-path-of-a-remote.git>
git push --all upstream
git push --tags upstream
```

Comment: To anyone using the code above , I would suggest `grep -v -- '->'` notation instead of `grep -v '\->'`. Grep assumes that anything starting with a dash is a flag. `--` acknowledges to the program that there are no flags provided anymore. Escaping characters takes its toll on me :D

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following commands as a bash script with the first input being your existing source repo and the second input as your target repo.

```
mkdir migrate
git clone $1 migrate
cd migrate
git fetch origin
git remote add new-origin $2
git push -u new-origin --all
git push new-origin --tags
git remote set-head origin -d
git push new-origin refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

This assumes you've already created the target repo.

Answer (score 1):

**UI Method:** 
You can also do this via Github.com's UI - Private & Public Repos both work.

1. Create a new repo in your organization on github.com - Click green "Create Repository" button
   [image: Create new Repo Screen]
2. On next screen, the last option listed lets you clone your old repo to Github. *(See Highlight in blue)*
   [image: Select Repository Source]
3. Next enter your old bitbucket repo url as below.
   *(yes, private repo is fine - keep reading - next step is auth :p)*
   [image: Old repo url in bitbucket]
4. Lastly it will ask for your login credentials, enter them and go make some coffee. It wont take long honestly.
   [image: Who might you be sir?]

BAM - and you're done. Personally I just use the CLI + Mirror that is the accepted answer on here ironically, but a dev asked me about this on my team the other day and thought it'd be helpful to have the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If the `upstream` is already added as a remote on the repository, then the following works without explicitly checking out all branches:

```
git fetch -pPt upstream
git push origin --tags "refs/remotes/upstream/*:refs/heads/*"
```

If you would like to not push the tags, then remove the `--tags` option.

Answer (score -5):

Hope this helps:

```
git remote add your-new-origin url-to-repo/repo.git
git push --all your-new-origin //pushes all branches
git push --tags your-new-origin //pushes all tags
```

Comment: This will only push branches that have been checked out locally. It does not pull ANY branches anyway